# Search for specific string format, like 'KB9999999' (7 digit) where '9' is use as a wildcard

Tags: powershell

I'm learning Powershell.

I found this module so useful:
**Get-WindowsUpdate**

From Microsoft Powershell
https://www.powershellgallery.com/

And it's working awesome for me! I do recommend it to you, specially if you work Backstage/Remote

Now, I can update all, or manually do 1 update at a time.

My IT Manager wants me to install only those KB (Windows Update) instead the mixed list that module will give you (such as drivers, bios update, etc)

Therefore I need a Powershell command lines for:

1. Get the result of Get-WindowsUpdate (if you use it 'as is', it will list all pending updates) to a file.
2. Search the file for the string format 'KB9999999' (7 digit) where '9' or whatever symbol is a wildcard instead, so any present number (only) will do the match.
3. After find each of them, output it to a unique file.
4. Then with that unique file do ANOTHER LOOP to install those, like

```
--- Loop (ForEach-Object??)
Get-WindowsUpdate -KBArticleID KB9999999 -Install (where KB9999999 is taken from the output file one by one.
--- Loop
```

I hope I made myself clear on the situation.
Thanks for any help ! :)

Here is how it works:

```
# -------------------------- Install Windows Update via Powershell
# Allow script execution (disabled by default)
Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted
# Native Windows module
Install-Module PSWindowsUpdate
# Gallery Windows module
Install-Module -Name PendingReboot
# Find out available Update
Get-WindowsUpdate

Here you get the full list
Examples depending what you will install

# **************** REVIEW UPDATE BEFORE TO CONTINUE  **************** 
# ----- Install all possible update. If need to reboot, add -AutoReboot
Get-WindowsUpdate -AcceptAll -Install
# ----- To install 1 by 1 by KD ID (example)
Get-WindowsUpdate -KBArticleID KB5022282 -Install
# ---- or do a bunch of them (example) Get-WindowsUpdate -KBArticleID KB4484527,  KB890830, KB5022546 -Install
# find out if there is any pending reboot
test-pendingreboot
# disable script execution
Set-ExecutionPolicy restricted
```

Comment: Good opportunity to learn regex, this looks fun: https://regexone.com/